# Push in a Stack char-value have different value

Tags: java, char, stack

everyone.
I need to put char-value in Stack:

```
        for(char ch: operand.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println("ch: " + ch);
        numericsOfTheOperand.push((int) ch);
        System.out.println("numericsOfTheOperand.peek() " + numericsOfTheOperand.peek());
    }
```

For example, operand: 456454
Output in console:

```
ch: 4
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 52
ch: 5
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 53
ch: 6
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 54
ch: 4
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 52
ch: 5
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 53
ch: 4
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 52
ch: 4
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 52
```

I don't understand, why value is different?
How can I resolve it?

Comment: How is your numericsOfTheOperand defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push `char` to a `Stack` you will need to declare it as a:

```
Stack<Character> numericsOfTheOperand = new Stack<>();
```

And then you can do your thing:

```
String operand = "456454";
for(char ch: operand.toCharArray()) {
    numericsOfTheOperand.push(ch);
    System.out.println("numericsOfTheOperand.peek() " + numericsOfTheOperand.peek());
}
```

Out:

```
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 4
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 5
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 6
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 4
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 5
numericsOfTheOperand.peek() 4
```

You were casting a `char` to `int` and thus getting the `int` value of it.